# Некорректный условный подсчёт вводимых чисел

Tags: c++

Есть у меня код на языке С++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    double L[7], S[7];
    int i, k, k1 , k2;
    k = k1 = k2 = 0;
    for (i = 0;i < 7;i++)
    {
        cout << '\n' << "L[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> L[i];
        S[i] = L[i] * 0.5;
        cout << "S[" << i << "]= " << S[i] << endl;
        if (S[i] > 0)  k = k++; 
        if (S[i] < 0)  k1 = k++; 
        if (S[i] == 0 && i % 2 == 0)  k2 = k2++; 
    }
    cout << " k = " << k << "; k1 = " << k1 << "; k2 = " << k2 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

По задумке k, k1 и k2 — это количество введённых, отрицательных и нулевых чисел соответственно.

Однако эти значения определяются некорректно. Вот полный вывод программы:

```
L[0]= -3.9  
S[0]= -1.95

L[1]= -7.1  
S[1]= -3.55

L[2]= 4.2  
S[2]= 2.1

L[3]= -1.3  
S[3]= -0.65

L[4]= 1.4  
S[4]= 0.7

L[5]= 2.2  
S[5]= 1.1

L[6]= -6.5  
S[6]= -3.25   
k = 7; k1 = 6; k2 = 0
```

Где я ошибся?

Comment: Заменить бессмыслицу `k = k++;`, `k1 = k++;` и `k2 = k2++;` на `k++;`, `k1++;` и `k2++;` соответственно

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon ответ не получилса ожидаемий до сих пор:  k = 7; k1 = 0; k2 = 0

Comment: значит вы сделали не так, как я написал. https://ideone.com/4U55uG

Comment: Вам же ясно написали, как надо исправить код. Вы не в состоянии даже это сделать?

Comment: Это каким это образом некая "лишняя библиотека" могла разрушить работоспособность вашего кода? Вы о чем? Никакой `#include <cmath>` тут ни в чем не виноват.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon благодарю за ответ. Помогли, жаль у меня ссылка сразу не отобразилась или типу того.

Comment: Классно мне вопрос задизали..теперь даже ответ на сообственной вопрос сделать немогу. Что не так то? Исправлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке:

> if (S[i] < 0)  k1 = k++;

припущена ошибка **k1 = k++;** - тоисть присвоено другое значение, к первому.
Више ответ с ненужной поправкой которая испортит сам код:

> В третьем if
>
> if (S[i] == 0)...

Тоисть ты предлагаешь проверку на несколько значений

```
if (S[i] == 0 && i % 2 == 0)
```

заменить на одно, это не верно, там индекс переверяетса на парность. Точнее если в непарной строке получитса ноль-умова не исполнитса.

Как зазначил @Drawn Raccoon:

> Заменить бессмыслицу `k = k++;`, `k1 = k++;` и `k2 = k2++;` на `k++;`, `k1++;` и `k2++;` соответственно

Если бы з саммого начала я написал именно так, код бы неимел ошибку *k1 = k++;*

Answer (score 0):

В третьем if

```
if (S[i] == 0)
```

и как сказал Drawn Raccoon заменить

```
k = k++;
k1 = k++;
k2 = k2++;
```

на

```
k++;
k1++;
k2++;
```

Comment: В третьем нету проблеми, только он работает коректно именно так, как нужно.

Comment: @Witalik Я запускал программу с правками и все корректно работало. Программа правильно отображала количество положительных, отрицательных и нулевых чисел. Не знаю, где у тебя могли появится проблемы

Comment: во-первых он сделал правки нужные, вы предлагаете заменить if(S[i]==0 && i%2==0) на if(S[i]==0), это фактически не правильно, по сколько в моём примере проверка несколько значений при помощи одного if. Ещё ошибка в 2 if, а не как вы указали в 3 (я дал правку вашему ответу по этому поводу).